# how can I solve "An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'kotlin-android']" this error?

Tags: flutter, dart

After cleaning the storage of my macbook,deleting some files my project does not build anymore for that error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/faridahmadov/flutter-projects/barsiba/android/app/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'kotlin-android']
> Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'.
   > Can't infer current AndroidGradlePluginVersion: Is the Android plugin applied?
```

I deleted android studio then downloaded again ,but did not work for me.How can I solve this problem?